# Как с помощью Selenium на яызке Python зажать кнопку на сайте на несколько секунд?

Tags: python, selenium

Как с помощью Selenium на яызке Python зажать кнопку на сайте на несколько секунд?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `element.click()` без зедаржки в цикле.

Comment: @cauf что такое "без задержки в цикле"?

Answer (score 2):

Тут поможет `click_and_hold()`

```
element = driver.find_element_by_что-нибудь
click_and_hold(on_element=element)
```